# How to load the ReactiveMongo for both linux and osx when defining the dependencies?

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I am trying to setup my RractiveMongo dependancy for both linux and osx platforms.

I tried this:

```
val mongoShadedNativeLinux = "org.reactivemongo"          % "reactivemongo-shaded-native"   % s"$reactivemongoVersion-linux-x86-64" classifier "linux-x86_64"
  val mongoShadedNative      = "org.reactivemongo"          % "reactivemongo-shaded-native"   % s"$reactivemongoVersion-osx-x86-64" classifier "natives-osx"
```

But I get an error:

> https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/reactivemongo/reactivemongo-shaded-native/0.20.3-osx-x86-64/reactivemongo-shaded-native-0.20.3-osx-x86-64-natives-osx.jar: not found:
> https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/reactivemongo/reactivemongo-shaded-native/0.20.3-osx-x86-64/reactivemongo-shaded-native-0.20.3-osx-x86-64-natives-osx.jar

How do I load the correct library?  And do I have to build the project on a linux server to build it for production (using linux for prod, osx for development)

Comment: Scala is compiled like a Java to the byte code. Byte code runs on JVM and libraries doesn't think about platform witch will be used on runtime. So this is the reason that scala libraries don't have versions for different OSs. Why you are trying specify libs for different OSs?

Comment: @BorisAzanov because I am developing on osx, and production is linux...

Comment: you can see there are different versions for osx and linux: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reactivemongo/reactivemongo-shaded-native

Comment: Why would you load both? You need to indicate the dependency according the target env, which is either OSX or Linux, but not both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the build of the [demo application](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/reactivemongo-demo-app/blob/master/build.sbt#L23), you can customize the dependency according OS.

```scala
libraryDependencies += {
  val os = sys.props.get("os.name") match {
    case Some(osx) if osx.toLowerCase.startsWith("mac") =>
      "osx"

    case _ =>
      "linux"
  }

  val (playVer, nativeVer) = reactiveMongoVer.split("-").toList match {
    case major :: Nil =>
      s"${major}-play27" -> s"${major}-${os}-x86-64"

    case vs @ _ => {
      val pv = ((vs.init :+ "play27") ++ vs.lastOption.toList)
      val nv = ((vs.init :+ os :+ "x86-64") ++ vs.lastOption.toList)

      pv.mkString("-") -> nv.mkString("-")
    }
  }

  "org.reactivemongo" % "reactivemongo-shaded-native" % nativeVer
}
```

You can replace `sys.props.get("os.name")` by `sys.env.get("FOO")`, to define the target OS using a environment variable at build-time.